# VLOOKUP from another sheet, apply formula every nth row

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm working on the below formula to Vlookup data from another sheet. The formula must be placed on the 14th column, and every 7 rows, vlookuping the first column value.

```
Sub test3()
'Vlookuping on Column N 


Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row 'Checks last row with data

Dim cel As Range, rng As Range

Dim sheetName, lookupFrom, myRange           'variables
sheetName = "Plan2" 'the worksheet i want to get data from
lookupFrom = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -14).Address '
myRange = "'" & sheetName & "'!1:1048576"

For i = 3 To lastRow Step 7 '
    Cells(i, 14).Select      'i= first value; step= lines to jump
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & lookupFrom & ";" & myRange & "; 14; FALSE)"

Next i

End Sub
```

[Example Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoLsQ.jpg)

I want to place the formula on the pink cells (column N), vlookuping the pink value from the first cell on another worksheet. My actual formula isn't even executing.

Comment: To make the formula work, replace the `;` with `,`.  vba is very US English centric and the formula must be entered in as if your computer were set to US English locality.

Comment: Thanks, it almost works. However it opens a box for me to select the sheet i want to extract data from for every variable. Is there a way i could design the macro to work with this sheet only?

Comment: Then check your spelling on the `Plan2`. make sure it is spelled exactly as the actual sheet name.

Comment: It's painful to watch, please modify your last 2 lines to : `Cells(i, 14).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & lookupFrom & "," & myRange & ", 14, FALSE)"`

Comment: @Serveira is the `Vlookup` found a match on `ColumnA` in "Plan2" sheet, does it return the value of the 14th Column in "Plan2" ? or from this sheet ? (where you placed the image of the table)

Comment: It returns the value of the 14th column in "Plan2". I'm having problems using the `lookupFrom = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -13)`, as it offsets the currently active cell, but it should offset the cell in the column N, to lookup the "pink 1" in the first column.

Comment: In the meanwhile I've been trying to make it work by selecting the cell N3 and running the macro. I can't seem to get the correct lookup value from `lookupFrom = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -14)`. Shouldn't this select the cell A2 value as the variable for vlookup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, with 2 exceptions:

1.Modify "**VlookRes**" to your Sheet name -  where you want to results to be.

2.You have **Merged Cells** in Column A (according to your image uploaded), you are merging Rows 2 untill 6 in column A, this means that the value of **Cell A3 will be 0**. If you want the values to read from the third row, start the merging from row 3 (and soon for the next values in Column A).

```
Option Explicit

Sub test3()

'Vlookuping on Column N

Dim ShtPlan     As Worksheet
Dim ActSht      As Worksheet
Dim lastRow     As Long
Dim sheetName   As String
Dim lookupFrom  As String
Dim myRange     As String
Dim i           As Long

' modify this Sheet Name to your sheet name (where you want to keep your results)
Set ActSht = Sheets("VlookRes")
lastRow = ActSht.Cells(ActSht.Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row ' Checks last row with data

sheetName = "Plan2" 'the worksheet i want to get data from
Set ShtPlan = Sheets(sheetName)

myRange = "'" & sheetName & "'!1:1048576"

For i = 3 To lastRow Step 7
    lookupFrom = ActSht.Cells(i, 1).Address ' ActiveCell.Offset(0, -14).Address '
    Cells(i, 14).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & lookupFrom & "," & myRange & ", 14, FALSE)"
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks neat and works perfectly. I just modified `lookupFrom` to  `lookupFrom = ActSht.Cells(i - 1, 1).Address`, for it to return the merged cell.

Comment: Mr. Shai, where would I need to modificate this code to get information from another (closed) workbook? Is that possible?

Comment: This is another story all together, maybe you find what you are looking at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823845/how-to-access-a-closed-excel-workbook-using-vlookup-vba